# Excute bash script in jupyter notebook but get the error mkdir: command not found

Tags: bash, jupyter-notebook

I'm new to jupyter notebook & bash and now I'm stuck on this problem. I installed m2-bash in the active environment and the shell script is being excuted as I can see the output of echo function, but it retuens the error with the mkdir command:
*download_staffs.sh: line 7: mkdir: command not found*

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I'm on windows machine and could this be the reason?...

Comment: Make sure that the directory containing `mkdir` is listed in the `PATH` variable.

Comment: This idea came to my mind before but I don't know how to check the PATH on jupyter notebook. I went to the usr/bin directory of the current env and I can see bash and sh but no there is no mkdir, moment ago I just downloaded the win-bash and I can see the mkdir command at the same level of bash in win-bash. I can excute the sciprt from win-bash now. But how to excute it in jupyter-notebook? It seems I have to install other bash package instead of m2-bash?